# Domino 8.5.3: Modify Subject of Incoming Email

Tags: email-server, filtering, ibm-domino, agent

I am a newbie in managing and development for Domino. Recently, I have request from other teams at work to set up a filter or agent for incoming mail.

This is the requirement for the request:

1. Look for Incoming Mail addressed to #CRITICAL (mutlipurpose, internal group containing a list of engineers)
2. For mail matching Point 1, append "For Immediate Action: " to the front of the Subject

Some restrictions I have:

1. Only the Domino server is under my charge, not to touch on network-side or other servers
2. No 3rd party software to be installed

I have gone through the configurations in the Domino server and the closest thing I have to filtering Email is the Router/SMTP > Restrictions... > Rules. But this is not able to fulfill Point 2 in any way.

Is this even possible using just Domino server settings, or through agents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used my Google-fu and managed to find some important stuff like `notesSession.DocumentContext`, 'Before new mail arrives' agents.

Finally implemented it in this way:

1. Create a new database and use Mail Template on it.
2. Assign the new database as a Mail-In DB.
3. Create a 'Before new mail arrives' agent to process incoming mail (append text to `maildoc.Subject`, `maildoc.Importance` etc...) and forward them to the engineers
4. Inform all involved parties about this new address that they should only send 'Critical' requests and alerts
5. Let the agent work it's magic.

I got the 'template' from [here](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/nd6forum.nsf/DateAllFlatWeb/3448d6fdff3544d6852578db00617c97?OpenDocument) in case anyone is interested.

Comment: If you implement a "Before new mail arrives" please make sure you understand the notes.ini tag [AMgr_DisableMailLookup](http://www.lntoolbox.com/en/notesini-reference/bycategory/43-agent_manager/95-amgrdisablemaillookup.html) and the IBM Document ["Caveats with 'After new mail has arrived' triggered agents on Domino servers"](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21099178)

Answer (score 0):

You couldn´t modifize the subject from a email out of the box. But maybe I can show you another ways.

Some questions:

1.)
Did you have a Lotus Domino Developer at Hand or did you maybe have Developer knowledge (i didn´t think thats the case, but asking wouldn´t hurt anyway)

2.)
Would it be possible that you change the design from the user mailfiles?

Answer (score 0):

First I would suggest by not modifying the subject line at all.

While it is possible there are implications in doing this. For example if the mails are signed, you will end up erasing that signature and replacing it with the user running the code (which could be user, server or agent ID depending who runs it).

The easiest way is to create a mail rule. Have it that if it detects the subject you are looking for, then mark it as high priority. You can also have it copy to a folder called "For immediate attention" that the user can click on.

That option allows you to do this "out of the box".

The next option is to modify the view of the inbox to flag the subject line in question. This requires coding knowledge.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I never knew about the 'signature being erase', thanks for bringing it to my attention. Currently I sort of implemented it by having incoming go to a mail-in db and have an agent sort out the processing. The guys seem to be happy with it now, but I'll take note of your suggestion if improvements/future implementations require something like that. :)